# Обучение модели для классификации изображений с несколькими вводами

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь сделать модель, которая будет классифицировать изображение не только по самому изображению, но и по его признакам. Пример:

Есть изображение, к примеру, автомобиля.

Есть его признаки: вес, объем двигателя, цена.

Путь будет, допустим, 1700кг, 2.0, 3000$.

Как можно реализовать архитектуру нейросети так, чтобы для сверхточных слоев подавалось изображение самой машины, а для нижних, полносвязанных - подавались признаки, а затем и метка?

Что-то типа такого:

y_label = [[0,0,1], [1700, 2, 3000]] # Просто из головы,пусть будет 0,0,1 - это какой-нибудь минивэн, а 1700, 2 и 3000 - "признаки" минивэна.

Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема? Подаете сразу все свои признаки, включая "вес, объем двигателя, цена" на вход сети в надежде, что она сама разберется, какие веса на каких слоях назначать.

Впрочем, если бы такая задача стояла передо мной, я бы сначала обучил бы нейросеть по картинке делать вывод, например "минивен с уверенностью 0.73", а потом бы этот результат, на ряду с "вес, объем двигателя, цена" подавал бы на вход обычному классическому классификатору.

Просто мне кажется для каждой задачи (или подзадачи) - свой метод, а не один метод на все задачи.

Вот как-то так.

Comment: по-моему, вариант со смешиванием обычных данных с растровыми данными (с картинкой) - не совсем рабочий. Представьте что на входе 4D тензор с `N` картинками размерности `(N, 50, 50, 3)` как добавить к этому тензору доп. информацию? Какая получится размерность в итоге?

Comment: Хм... Хороший вариант. Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @ MaxU  -  так и я о том-же. Поэтому и написал про задачи и методы. А первый абзац - для тех, кто свято верит в универсальность и всемогущность нейросетей.